# StringVar.set("...") does not work in multiple tkinter windows

Tags: python, tkinter

My program has a library which opens a new window

This is the library (its called make_entry):

```
from tkinter import *

def Create():
    Window = Tk() # window    
    Window.geometry("900x500+50+50") # heightxwidth+x+y

    mainPanel = Canvas(Window, width = 900, height = 500) # main screen
    mainPanel.pack()

    anyvar = StringVar() # the text in the entry
    entry = Entry(mainPanel, width = 40, font = ("Purisa", 12, "bold"), justify = "center", textvariable = anyvar) # the entry
    mainPanel.create_window(200, 100, window = entry)
    anyvar.set("This doesnt work!!!!!")

    Window.mainloop()

#Create()
```

If I run this library by itself then everything works fine, but when I import it from another program the only thing which doesn't work is `anyvar.set("This doesnt work!!!!!")`.

Here is where I import it: (most of this code is cut out)

```
from tkinter import *
Window = Tk()
import make_entry
make_entry.Create()
Window.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to fix this problem without removing any of the windows?

Comment: Don't use `from tkinter import *`, import what you need

Comment: That was from a larger program, I had quite a lot of functions in. Also how do you have 1 reputation but 9 gold badges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two instances of Tk() which confuses Tkinter.  I am guessing that the StringVar() is going to the other (first) instance.  Instead, pass the only instance to the function, and use a Toplevel for a new window.

```
from tkinter import *

def Create(root):
    window=Toplevel(root)    
    window.geometry("900x500+50+50") # heightxwidth+x+y

    mainpanel = Canvas(window, width = 900, height = 500) # main screen
    mainpanel.pack()

    anyvar = StringVar() # the text in the entry
    entry = Entry(mainpanel, width = 40, font = ("Purisa", 12, "bold"), justify = "center", textvariable = anyvar) # the entry
    mainpanel.create_window(200, 100, window = entry)
    anyvar.set("This doesnt work!!!!!")
```

and

```
from tkinter import *
Window = Tk()
import make_entry
make_entry.Create(Window)
Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Tom Fuller: There are not only two Tk instances, but mainloop is run on each.  Each program should have one Tk instance and one .mainloop call.  My answer is otherwise identical to Curly Joe's.